# How to vertical align text next to image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregoryagu/F5ccG/)

```
<div class="container">
    <img style="margin: 10px;" src="~/Content/Images/x.png"  alt="" width="400"  />
    <span style="margin-left: 50px;" class="h3" >Connecting People & Businesses Since 1992</span>
</div>
```

The above displays just fine in a desktop browser.  However, when viewed on a mobile device, the text that should remain to the right of the image wraps underneath the image.

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="col-md-6" src="~/Content/Images/x.png" />
    <span class="col-md-6 h3" >Connecting People & Businesses Since 1992</span>
</div>
```

So how do I Bootstrap this?  I have tried using a col-md-6 class, but the text on the right no longer is vertically centered after using the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" src="~/Content/Images/x.png" />
    <span class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 h3" >Connecting People & Businesses Since 1992</span>
</div>
```

col-md-6 means that everything above 'tablet' size is using 6 out of 12 columns. and everything below that size will revery to the full 12 of 12 because you did not specify anything [thats what you want except you want it all the way down to 'xs' size.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple two column table.
Apply "vertical-align:middle" to the td element.